# "Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 0" issue in MIPS

Tags: mips

My code is for a program that counts the number in an array. The numbers should only be between 0 and 49 (both included). This is the error I keep seeing: <kbd>"Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 0"</kbd> The snippet of the code responsible for the error is: -

```
outOfRange:
    li $v0, 0
    syscall
```

I tried replacing 0 with 1 and it shows that the program is running successfully, however, it doesn't show any output, just this: -

00

-- program is finished running --

Comment: The contents of `$v0` specifies what `syscall` will do.  0 is not defined (thus the error you're getting), 1 is "print integer" for example.  Each syscall requires additional registers to provide whatever parameters it needs; in the case of "print integer", the integer needs to be in `$a0`.

Comment: As already stated, that is an ill formed syscall.  What do you think it should do with that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you think it should do something else with that ill formed syscall?  A runtime error is the right way to handle an ill formed syscall.